# how can I create conditional HTML displays in PHP

Tags: php, html, navigation

I'm trying to find out how I can create a condition display of an HTML `div` like:

```
<div class="home">
<a href="/">
</div>
```

What I want to accomplish is to write something in PHP that will prevent the div from displaying on the main page `/`. So it will display on all pages except `/`. The `/` is actually `index.html`, but I have it rewritten to always be `/`.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: I won't recommend you to implement PHP rules in an HTML file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] != '/index.html'): ?>
    <div class="home">
        <a href="/">
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You have to specify `/index.html` in this case, because although it shows only `/` in your browser, `SCRIPT_NAME` gets the script/file name.

Comment: May I ask up a follow up question? How could I edit that for usage to only display on a certain page, rather than every page except specified, like in this case. Do I just remove the `!`?

Comment: Sure you may. `!=` means `not equal to`, while `==` means `equal to`, so you can use `==` do denote on what page to show the HTML. If you need more pages per condition, perhaps the best way would be to make an array of page names and then use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should work pretty well, since $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] will always be the name of the actual file being processed regardless of whether or not you're using URL Rewrite. Just place the code or HTML that you want to be output into the //Show section and it should work fine

```
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "index.html") {
    //Hide
    }
else {
    //Show
    }
```

You could also use a simpler version without the *else* statement, which would read as follows

```
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) !== "index.html") {
    //Show
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] != '/index.html') 
{
echo<<<_HTML
<div class="home">
    <a href="/">
</div>
_HTML;
}
?>
```